# Filter subgrid lookup in dynamic crm 2013

Tags: filter, dynamics-crm, lookup, subgrid

After I click the "+" button on the subgrid in an entity form , 
the dynamic crm open a lookup field in the subgrid. 
Is anyone know how can i filter this lookup field  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can help you to solve the problem:
http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2014/04/21/filter-n-n-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2013

The example is for **N:N** relationship, if you are working on **1:N** subgrid, please change the method "**Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated**" to "**Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridStandard**"

Hope this helps anyone who stucks in such issue.